# boolean not becoming false python

Tags: python

```
boolean = True
print ("Enter your list of numbers. Type \"done\" when you are finished entering all your numbers ")

def collectNumbers(number):


    if number is ("done"):
        boolean == False #but it never actually becomes false
    if boolean == True:
        number = input("Enter a number ")
        listofNumbers.append(number)
        collectNumbers(None)
    else:
        print ("That is not a number. Please drink some bleach.")
        collectNumbers(None)
```

it returns:

```
Enter a number 1
Enter a number 2
Enter a number 3
Enter a number 4
Enter a number done
Enter a number done
Enter a number done
Enter a number
```

it never breaks out of the function despite me typing in "done". "boolean" doesn't become "false" and thus the function never breaks out.

Comment: Assignment is done with `=`, not `==`... Furthermore you should **not** use `is` but `==` to **compare strings**, since not all strings are interned.

Comment: You also might want to use `==` instead of `is` for string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
if number == "done": #change is to == and strip ()
    boolean = False  #change == to =
```